# Add an Admin Role to the Devise's User Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I think my question is simple, I followed step by step the second option that appears on this page [How To: Add an Admin Role](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-an-Admin-Role). Now I would like to use current_user.admin? with the before_action method (thus `before_action :current_user.admin?`), but I see this error.

```
**undefined method `admin?' for :current_user:Symbol**
```

I can't even use the method admin with the before_action method, and if you are wondering, yes, I'm logged.

Now, what I can do is define a new method in the controller, such as admin_only thus.

```
  def admin_only
    if !current_user.admin then
      redirect_to :back, :alert => "Access denied."
    end
  end
```

And then use `before_action :admin_only` and it works well, but I think it breaks a little the logic of the controller to define a method such as admin_only. So... is there a way to filter administrators without having to define new methods in the controller?.

Comment: Adding a method is the way to go, you could add that as a protected method to ApplicationController and only add before_action to necessary controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You should define a method to do that. Because `before_action` need you to have an defined action, and tell rails to call it by pass its name as a symbol.

And that's why you get an undefined method error, cause `:current_user` is just a symbol, not the user object you expected.